# Get connection string of my SQL Server without Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, web-config, connection-string

I finished my Asp.net Mvc application and want to deploy it to server.

My problem is the connection string for database server doesn't have Visual Studio to connect with SQL and know connection string, I want to know how to get the connection string without Visual Studio - what is the easiest way to get it to replace the old one in `web.config`?

Comment: The template for a connection string is :  connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=False;User Id=userid;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" /.  If you know the name of the server, the database, the user ID and password, you should be able to simply construct the string.

Comment: You can look at connection string syntax at [www.connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Comment: ok i will see thank you

Answer (score 3):

First create a file in your desktop with **udl** format.
Then double click on it and enter your database info and press ok.
open the file with notepad and you will see connection string.